# Correlation Id missing dashes with MassTransit and Azure Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

Dashes are removed from the correlation id Guid value in messages while using MassTransit and Azure Service Bus.

Here is how we set the correlation id, which is according to the [documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/messages#message-correlation):

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
      MessageCorrelation.UseCorrelationId<MyMessage>(x => Guid.NewGuid());
     x.AddConsumer<...Consumer>();
     x.UsingAzureServiceBus((IBusRegistrationContext context, IServiceBusBusFactoryConfigurator cfg) =>
     {
          cfg.Host(config.AzureServiceBus.ConnectionString);               
          ....
     }
}
```

[image]

We are on MassTransit nuget *v8.0.6* but trying with 8.0.12 didn't help.

I have not found any reported issues related to this on [masstransit github repo](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues).

It seems like a bug as I cannot think of any reason why dashes should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

I found it [here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/5c691a106441c15d2bbad00d579f2a845004fe3c/src/Transports/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/AzureServiceBusTransport/ServiceBusSendTransportContext.cs#L184) by searching the MassTransit code:

```
if (context.CorrelationId.HasValue)
    message.CorrelationId = context.CorrelationId.Value.ToString("N");
```

So indeed, it seems like the developers chose that particular format on purpose.